# Run tests in 64-bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, mstest

I got a ADO.NET driver which is compiled as 64-bit. I therefore need to run mstests in 64-bit mode. Is that possible?

(the dev machine is 64bit).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Visual Studio has a built in option for this. It was a bit hard to find (if you do not know where to look).

Doubleclick on the `local.testsettings` file in *Solution Explorer* and select `Hosts` in the listbox. Then change as the image shows.

You must do your tests in a 64-bit OS and your application should be compiled with `AnyCPU`.

[image: Setting to change]

Comment: This fixed the **SharePoint** `FileNotFoundException` when creating `SPSite`. **MSTest** requires the **x64 Test Runner** for Sharepoint `SPSite` testing when running IIS 6 in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier in Visual studio 2013. Select Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture->x64 before running the tests

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution described in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danielvl/archive/2009/03/28/run-mstest-exe-as-native-64-bit-process.aspx):

1. Backup `mstest.exe` and run `CorFlags.exe MSTest.exe /32BIT- /Force` to remove the 32-bit flag
2. Run your tests with `/noisolation`: `MSTest.exe /testcontainer:<your-assembly> /resultsfile:<your-results-file> /noisolation`
3. If `MSTest.exe` fails after modification, run `reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\MSTest,b03f5f7f11d50a3a /f` to skip strong name verification

Comment: Wouldn't that make mstest run as 64bit for all projects/solutions? I just want to do it for a specific project.

Comment: Running without `/noisolation` should make you run with `VSTestHost.exe` which is still 32-bit. I haven't tried myself, though. Be sure to backup `mstest.exe`. As an alternative, you can switch back and forth between 32- and 64-bit `mstest.exe` using scripts.

Comment: Maybe you can copy `mstest.exe` as `mstest64.exe` and run the flag removal and tests with that?